# ActiveModel responsibility for conversion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, activerecord

I have a Rails application that captures information from an external datasource. This information gets collected into a `raw_data` attribute, saved and an ActiveJob in charge of doing the processing is scheduled.

```rb
capture = Capture.create(raw_data: data)
ProcessCaptureJob.perform_later(capture)
```

The data processing is done later in an offline process, the issue is: Who is in charge of doing the conversion?

The Model?

```rb
def convert
  update(attr1: raw_data['attr1a'] + raw_data['attr1b']
end
```

Or the Job?

```rb
def perform(capture)
  capture.attr1 = capture.raw_data['attr1a'] + capture.raw_data['attr1b']
  capture.save
end
```

The idea behind ActiveModel is that the Model is responsible of all of its data-related use cases, but is this a data-related issue or it's better to leave that responsability to an external job?

Comment: They are essentially the same thing, but probably it's better to call the `convert` method from the job, because it gives you the option of calling it from elsewhere as well, should you come across that need.

Comment: Yes, but increasing its complexity, what if the raw_data could come from different providers? In that case a converter would be better or it should include a converter in that moment?

Comment: i dunno. when you look at it that closely you're getting into the land of a thousand design patterns. It's really subjective

Comment: Another option to consider is using a service object to do the conversion, called by the job, which then updates the model with the result.